# Creating and Running runnable jar on hadoop's prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar

I wanted to play around with the sample WordCount program provided in the Hadoop's package. Thus, I created a custom project in eclipse and copied the entire wordcount code in my custom class. I also included all the external Hadoop jars in the build path of the project. And finally, tried to create a Runnable JAR: File -> Export -> Java Tab -> Runnable Jar.

But, I got the error in the jar creation as:  **Exported with compile warnings: custom_project/src/custom_package/CustomWordCount.java**

Inspite of the code being error free, the jar creation is giving me an issue. How to solve this issue?

Comment: It says expoted with warnuings - sounds like jar was made. Did you check? Also which version of eclipse are you using and which method did you use? Did you specify main class?

Comment: I just made a class with a unused import. Exported it as a runnnable  jar and ran it from exploer. it opened a message box as expected. I do not think eclipse has any issue making a jar with warnings. do not know about what else you changed / what hadoop was expecting

Comment: @tgkprog As u said, the jar gets created inspite of the error mentioned above.But, when you open the MANIFEST.MF file inside the jar, the <Main-Class> tag does not point to the Main class file. 

I am using Eclipse Kepler version 4.3.1

Comment: Mine did. You need to specify the Run config. I have two main classes so had to choose the right one. When i double click jar in explorer it opened the Frame app (test app)

Comment: Exactly that's what I did. Specified the right class of corresponding project in the Run config. But, for me the jar export was not successful

Comment: what version of eclipse? also in my answer i attached a sample, maybe you can unzip that and see in your eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not allow us to create a Runnable Jar with the code with warnings.

For instance,

1) Unused imports(packages)
2) Deprecated warnings, etc.

Thus, make sure, you take care of all of these before creating the jar. Also, in the sample  WordCount code of hadoop, an instance of Job class is created. Which is deprecated. And thus, you will definitely face issues in that matter. Thus, to overcome that, please delete the line:
 *Delete the Job job = new Job (conf, "basic word count");*

and include the line below:
*Job job = Job.getInstance();*

Comment: I do not think that is true, its just an ant task (in latest eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Export does not get stopped if you had compile warnings. even if you have errors other class files will get packaged as its an independent ant script

Sample project with saved generated files [Run sample](http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/java/Run1.zip%20source%20files)

Bld.xml made by IDE export (eclipse)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project Run1 with libraries in sub-folder">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="D:/U/t/workspace/1/Run1/o/RunApp.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="m.TT"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="D:/U/t/workspace/1/Run1/bin"/>
        </jar>
        <delete dir="D:/U/t/workspace/1/Run1/o/RunApp_lib"/>
        <mkdir dir="D:/U/t/workspace/1/Run1/o/RunApp_lib"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I am not able to download the sample files. Getting a server error: Could not locate the files.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true anymore. I've just exported as Runnable jar my project from Kepler to run on a Hadoop cluster  and it saved the jar file without any problem, with lots of warnings.